# Embedding Icons in Rails text_field placholder with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, font-awesome

I am working on a rails project and it is using bootstrap and I want to embed an icon from awesome font into the placeholder of a text field. The code looks like this:

```
#search
  = form_for :search, url: topic_search_path do |f|
    = f.text_field :search_query, placeholder: "Search for topics..."
```

I know that I'm supposed to normally make an italic tag with the class being the icon I want to reference, but I'm lost on how exactly I'm supposed to embed that in the placeholder let alone in a rails form_for block written with HAML. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the character in the value of the `plaeholder` the old–fashioned way using an entity, as long as you first set the style of the `input` so that the font is `FontAwesome` (or at least the first font in the stack is `FontAwsome`.

For example, if you want to use the [`icon-search` icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/search/), which is at code point `F002` (the codepoint is on the icons web page), then you want to generate something like this (assuming you have Font Awesome set up for the page):

```html
<style>
input /* be more selective here if you want */ {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
</style>

<input placeholder="&#xf002; Search for topics...">
```

To generate this from the `text_field` method, just pass the entity as part of the value of the `placeholder` key in the options hash (you may need to use `.html_safe` here, I haven’t tested this last bit):

```haml
= f.text_field :search_query, placeholder: "&#xf002; Search for topics..."
```

(You’ll still need to style the `input` so that it uses the right font, as above.)

Comment: You definitely need the .html_safe to get it to show up, although it's only showing me a square in the search bar.. http://imgur.com/9xAnMOb (the other magnifying glass is my temporary fix by placing it next to the search bar).

Comment: @jaredsmith have you set the `font-family` for the input in a `style` block somewhere? A square showing up suggests the browser is using a font that doesn’t have that character.

Comment: Yes in the css file I did, without it my text definitely looks different so I'm sure the style is being applied as well. For fontawesome I'm using the font-awesome-rails gem, I'm not sure if that makes a difference but thought I should mention.

Comment: So I found that it was the gem not loading the font correctly and that  if you use fontawesome's cdn in the header the magnifying glass shows up. Thanks for the help!